# How to Connect Analysis Services Database from Internet?

Tags: sql-server

please provide me the details on
How to Connect Analysis Services Database from Internet?

i am using ASp.net and Sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect using the servername (DNS-name or IP-name) and the database name. The server needs to allow connections from the internet, and make sure there are no firewalls in between that stops the connection.

Comment: You have to provide more details about your problem before we can give you a better answer. Please update your question with information about what software you're using, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way for allowing your users to connect, a good solution is to use Excel over the web using IIS, HTTPS and the msmdpump.dll. There is an article describing the process here for SQL 2005 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917711.aspx

or for SQL 2008 http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx

This explains how to connect Excel http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940167